# Confusion about the meaning of re and rπ

Tags: bjt

In BJT small-signal models there is both r<sub>e</sub> and r<sub>π</sub> parameters. They both represent the dynamic resistor between the base and the emitter terminals.

But I read that they are different by a factor of β as:

> r<sub>π</sub> = β × r<sub>e</sub>

I know the concept of transconductance *g*<sub>m</sub>. It is the slope of the  Ic Vbe plot at a fixed bias collector current i.e: *g*<sub>m</sub>=∂Ic/∂Vbe.

And as definition r<sub>e</sub> = 1/ *g*<sub>m</sub>.

So what I understand is that r<sub>e</sub> is the change in Vbe with respect to a change in Ic.

Secondly r<sub>π</sub> is the change in Vbe with respect to a change in Ib.

Since there Ic = Ib × β this yields to  r<sub>π</sub> = β × r<sub>e</sub>

You might think what is my question here. Even though the formulas yield this relation between  r<sub>e</sub> and r<sub>π</sub>, I don't quite understand how they represent the same thing aka the "dynamic resistance between the base and emitter terminals".

I mean their definitions are same but yet they are different things. They are both the dynamic resistance between the base and emitter terminals in my mind. But they differ by a factor of β. I'm really confused about the approach. Is it about where we look at the base from?

Comment: Just use KVL. I think you'll see that \$I_B=\frac{V_{TH}-V_{BE}}{R_{TH}+\left(\beta+1\right)R_E}\$. Note here that for base current calcs the emitter resistance is multiplied by \$\beta+1\$. Similarly, \$I_E=\frac{V_{TH}-V_{BE}}{\frac{R_{TH}}{\beta+1}+R_E}\$. And here, the base Thevenin resistance is divided by \$\beta+1\$ to reflect it to the emitter for calcs there. It just depends on what you care about at the time. Of course, \$r_e\$ and \$r_\pi\$ are AC dynamic resistances. But the concept still applies for small signal analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I don't quite understand how they represent the same thing aka the "dynamic resistance between the base and emitter terminals".*

**You are completely right**. The term re does NOT represent any resistance between the nodes E and B. My suggestion: Forget the term re and always use 1/gm instead of re.

Some people say (and think... because they have read this somewhere) that the term re is something like a dynamic emitter-base resistance. But this is wrong!!

The quantity 1/gm has "ohms" as unit (because it is the inverse of a conductance) but, in fact, it is not a resistive element at all.

The quantity gm is a "transconductance" and it does NOT describe the current-to-voltage relation between two nodes - and the same applies, of course , to the inverse 1/gm. Hence, it is not a resistive element at all.

There is only one case, where it makes sense to write re=1/gm ....in the common base stage the input resistance at the emitter node is re=1/gm. But still - it is the input resistance (betwen E and common ground) and NOT the resistance between E and B.

**Comment**: A detailed analysis shows that the rather small input resistance at the E node can be explained as a result of negative feedback internal to the BJT (the relatively large E-B-resistance is reduced drastically to 1/gm due to negative feedback).

Comment: I'm not into the subject quite new but I think I see what you mean in that sense it is not a resistance. I think some engineers invented the "resistance looking into" thing to make re a resistance. I just saw a user ak-94's answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/157638/161776 I didn't think of it like that before.

Comment: Yes - looking into a certain node gives the input resistance (which is the resistance between that node and GROUND). But your question was if re is a kind of resistance between E and B (internal emitter resistance or something like that). And the answer is : NO ! A resistor describes the voltage-current ratio between two nodes. However, looking into the E node, tlhis is not the case because the voltage between B and E is Vbe, but the current goes through the node C.

Comment: I see I mixed up the concepts.

Comment: Just one more last question: When Vbe changes Ic changes so we can find the transconductance. So Vbe controls Ic in general... But is the opposite correct? In active region, if one causes a change in Ic(maybe by temperature or resistance change) would Vbe change according to the transconductance relation? Is causality valid both way? (I also ask because re is dVbe/dIe sounds like change in Ic causes a change in Vbe)

Comment: Look at the slope of the emitter-base junction at 1uA or 10uA or 100uA or 1mA or 10mA. That is the gm or 1/gm.

Comment: Clear answer: No - causality works only with Vbe as the controlling quantity (and Ic as the controlled variable).

Answer (score 8):

\$r_\pi\$ is an input resistance looking into the base with emitter terminal at AC ground.

[image]

\$\Large r_\pi\ = \frac{d V_{BE}}{dI_B} = \frac{V_T}{I_B} = \frac{\beta}{g_m} = (\beta+1)r_e \$

On the other hand \$r_e\$ is an input resistance looking into the emitter terminal with the base terminal at AC ground.

[image]

\$ \Large r_e = \frac{dV_{BE}}{dI_E} = \frac{V_T}{I_E} = \frac{r_\pi}{\beta +1} = \frac{\alpha}{g_m} = \frac{\beta}{g_m (\beta +1)}  \$

Sometimes because \$I_E \approx I_C\$ we can we can simplify our life and assumed that \$r_e \approx \frac{1}{g_m}\$

http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/The%20Hybrid%20Pi%20and%20T%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Comment: Thanks for mentioning and clarifying the "looking into" difference. Where are these figures from?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFVrq.png

Comment: They are from the Fundamentals of Microelectronics. As for re see also here. http://users.physics.harvard.edu/~horowitz/aoe/sm/smlitlre.htm

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing two different models.

The hybrid π model includes a rπ element. The T model includes a re element.

The models are similar and the two resister elements represent much the same physical factor but are expressed differently because they sit differently in their respective models.

[image: model circuits]
Circuits from https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/ece3050/notes/bjt/BJTBasicsSu10.pdf