# Input Impedance of BJT CE Configuration different from Multisim simulation

Tags: transistors, bjt, impedance, multisim

[image: AC Analysis Results]

[image: Circuit]

[image: Input Impedance(R=Z)]

So as I derived, my input impedance should be Rb||rπ. But by substituting the value I obtain via the AC analysis from Multsim, I got different values. Tried a few times but still, the input impedance calculates not equal to Probe of Rin(where expression: V(Rin)/V(Rout).
I got no idea what've I missed.
It will be great if someone can help me with this!

Comment: Repeat your measurements for a lower frequency. Set  V2 frequency to 1kHz.

Comment: G36 is right. Your calculations are correct for low to mid (e.g. audio) frequency range. Because the transistor model for high frequency (e.g. MHz range) is different than that for low to mid frequencies.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I tried, but still it does not "tally" :(

Comment: Try to show as your hand calculation for Rin and the simulation results. In your circuit, the collector current will be around Ic = 18mA. So, r_pi = 120 * 26 mV/18mA = 170Ω. Therefore Rin will be around 83Ω.  But also notice that the 10µF capacitor will have a reactance Xc at 1kHz equal 16Ω. And this will affect the simulation results. I don't even want to mention base spreading resistance r'bb and other factors.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for replying. I missed out the part that I_b=0.4mA obtained from IV-Graph, r_pi=64.5Ω, and R_B=(R_1 || R_2) = 162.208 Ω..Hence, I was thinking R_in=(R_B || r_pi)=(162.208 || 64.5) = 46.25Ω(expecting) but got 85.33420Ω instead.

Please feel free to let me know which part  missed..

Comment: You do not need to have any graph to be able to find the r_pi. You can use this equation r_pi = (β + 1)x 26mV/Ie where 26mV is a Thermal voltage and Ie is a quiescent point DC emiter current.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367321/confusion-about-the-meaning-of-re-and-r%cf%80/367430#367430