# What is the "small-signal impedance looking into the emitter"?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt

In section 2.3.2 of *The Art of Electronics* (3rd edition), the authors define \$r_\mathrm{e}=dV_{\mathrm{BE}}/dI_\mathrm{E}\$ (with fixed base voltage) for BJT transistors, and state that:

> This *intrinsic* emitter resistance, \$r_\mathrm{e}\$, acts as if it is in series with the emitter in all transistor circuits.

In section 2.3.3, discussing \$r_\mathrm{e}\$ in emitter follower, they write:

> \$r_\mathrm{e}\$ is paralleled by the emitter resistor \$R_\mathrm{E}\$, if used.

In particular, I don't understand the place of \$r_\mathrm{e}\$ in circuits. Why in emitter follower configuration it is in parallel with \$R_\mathrm{E}\$, not in series?

Comment: Take the derivative of the Shockley equation and solve it for \$\frac{\text{d}\,V_\text{BE}}{\text{d}\,\left(I_\text{C}\approx I_\text{E}\right)}\$. That is \$r_e^{ '}\$. If you plotted out \$V_\text{BE}\$ vs \$I_\text{C}\$, you'd have a curve. If you picked some point on the curve and put a ruler to it there and worked out the local slope at that point, that would be \$r_e^{ '}\$. It is NOT an Ohmic resistance that stays the same everywhere and it is NOT used in figuring out the DC quiescent operating point. It *only* applies to AC signals.

Comment: The meaning is kind of like this.... If the BJT is sitting still at some DC operating point, and if you try and jerk it away from that operating point, then its behavior will slide along a curve that has the slope of \$r_e^{\,'}\$ at that moment. Once it moves away from that point (if you are successful in moving it), then a new value of \$r_e^{\,'}\$ will describe any new attempt to move it from the new operating point. The slope is ever-changing. That's why you almost never want a circuit that has characteristics, ones you care about, depending on it.

Comment: Section 2.3.3 implies \$r_e = \dfrac{dV_{BE}}{dI_E}\$ (not 2.3.2).

Comment: In AC analysis, you short the VCC supply at emitter, and re becomes parallel to RE.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367321/confusion-about-the-meaning-of-re-and-r%cf%80/367430#367430

Comment: @Andy, see section 2.3.2, part B, the first line. (And note that \$I_\text{C}\approx I_\text{E}\$)

Comment: Ah, so it does @apadana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the emitter follower, we have two paths for an AC signal when we are looking into the emitter from the "load" resistance point of view.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWUHM5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see the first path is through \$R_E\$ to GND and the second one is through \$r_e\$ (emitter) and to AC ground at the base terminal.

\$r_e\$ is an AC dynamic resistances. This means that the \$r_e\$ does not represent any "real" resistance between the base and emitter.

Quick recap

**Static resistance** (capital \$R\$) is the ratio of the DC (Q - point) voltage across a device to the DC (Q-point) current through the device.

**Dynamic resistance** (lowercase \$r\$) is the ratio of the change in voltage across a device to the change in current through the device.

And for example, if we plot the V-I characteristic for a \$100Ω\$ resistor we well get this:

[image]

In the case of a resistor, we simply divide the voltage across it by the current through it. We see that at any point on its V-I curve, the resistance is a constant. Specifically, we see that:

\$R = \frac{1V}{10 mA} = 100Ω\$ or \$R= \frac{2 V}{20 mA} = 100Ω\$.

So the Static resistance is \$100Ω\$. But what about a Dynamic resistance?

Let us see

\$r = \frac{ΔU}{ΔI} = \frac{2V - 1V}{20mA - 10mA} = \frac{1V}{10mA} = 100Ω\$.

So far so good, nothing new here.

But what if we add a voltage source in series with a 100Ω resistor and we closed it into the black box. So we create a new two-terminal device.
And now we plot the V-I characteristic for our new device closed in the black box.

And the result is:

[image]

The curve is still linear, but it is offset from zero. So now let us try to find a Static resistance.
For \$Vin = 2V\$ we have a current of \$10mA\$, at \$3V\$ we have a current of \$20 mA\$, and at \$4V\$ the current is \$30 mA\$.

If we divide these voltages by their corresponding currents we obtain :

\$ R = \frac{2V}{10mA} = 200Ω\$

\$ R = \frac{3V}{20mA} = 150Ω\$

\$ R = \frac {4V}{30mA}= 133Ω\$

As you can see the Static resistance is no longer constant.

What we have found is the DC (static) resistance at three particular operating points and Ohm's law is still valid.

What about the Dynamic resistance for our new device in the black box?

\$r = \frac{3V - 2V}{20mA - 10mA} = 100Ω\$

\$r = \frac{4V - 1V}{30mA - 0mA} = 100Ω\$

\$r = \frac{4V - 0V}{30mA - (-10mA)} = 100Ω\$

As you can see the dynamic resistance is constant and equal to 100Ω.
So, from the AC signal point of view, our new device in a black box will behave just like an ordinary \$100Ω\$ resistor.

> One thing that I don't understand is why both base and collector are
> connected to ground here

The circuit I shown represents the equivalent circuit seen from an AC signal point of view.

In reality, the circuit will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMHQkf.png)</sup>

But from the AC signal point of view, the ideal DC voltage source has \$0Ω\$ internal resistance. And that's why AC signals are shorted by a DC voltage source. DC voltage is always constant so for any change in current there is no change in the voltage. So there is 0 Ohm internal resistance. Additionally, in the real-life circuit, we always using a bypass capacitor (big capacitor value so that \$Xc = 0Ω\$) connected in parallel to DC Voltage (\$C1\$). And this capacitor will short all AC-signal to the ground.

Thus, the AC equivalent circuit will look like this (including emitter dynamic resistance):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw3HZ6.png)</sup>

And here you find some theoretical background of how small-signal analysis work:

[https://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/section%205_6%20%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models%20lecture.pdf](https://www.ittc.ku.edu/%7Ejstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/section%205_6%20%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models%20lecture.pdf)

Comment: Your schematic helped a lot. One thing that I don't understand is why both base and collector are connected to ground here.

Comment: @apadana I update my answer.

Comment: This really generous answer also answered one of other unanswered questions I had in mind.

Comment: It seems to me that you have assumed that the output impedance of the signal source is almost zero. I think that's the only way the base can be at AC ground here. Emitter follower also reduces the impedance of a previous stage, though I'm not sure if this is relevant here.

Comment: Good point. Yes, I assumed that the signal source (Vin) internal resistance is \$r_s = 0Ω\$. If we include it then the impedance looking into the emitter is \$\large Z_{OUT} = R_E||(r_e + \frac{r_s}{\beta +1})\$  aditional I assumed \$R_B >> r_s\$ otherwise  \$ \large Z_{OUT} = R_E||(r_e + \frac{r_s||R_B}{\beta +1})\$

Comment: @G36 Nice. +1. By the way, you can shrink that overly large schematic nearer the bottom by using a tiny period (.) on the schematic. I use one and pick a small font size for it. It makes the software generate pictures of any smaller size you want, that way.

Comment: @jonk Thx for the comment, but whet I need to put this period "." the reduce the size of a schematic?

Answer (score 2):

> *Why in emitter follower configuration it is in parallel with \$R_E\$, not in series?*

Well, as a physical circuit \$R_E\$ appears to be in series with \$r_E\$ but, consider it from the perspective of the input signal (a la common base). The input signal sees a path to AC 0 volts via \$R_E\$ and the input signal also sees a path to AC 0 volts via \$r_E\$.

That means, from the perspective of the input signal at the emitter (CB), that there are two parallel paths to AC 0 volts hence, \$R_E\$ and \$r_E\$ are in parallel. It's no different when analysing a common collector circuit when considering the output impedance or, when analysing a common emitter circuit and examining the effective impedance at the physical emitter.

Comment: Speaking of an emitter follower, it is the output impedance which is identical to the parallel connection of RE and re (same as input impedance for common base configuration). The input impedance of the emitter follower is the series connection of rbe and beta*RE.

Comment: @LvW I've clarified that in my answer (hopefully).

Comment: Andy aka - last line: Should it be common collector?

Comment: @lvw d'oh yes it should!!

Comment: Thanks, but frankly, I don't understand your answer at all. Why does the input signal see two different paths to "AC 0 volts"? And what do you mean by "AC 0 volts"?

Comment: AC 0 volts is any low impedance node that may carry a DC level but, for AC signals represents a low impedance to ground (irrespective of the fact that it may be biased at some arbitrary DC voltage) @apadana

Comment: Path 1 is via the emitter and re to the base (a low impedance AC point or AC 0 volts) and, path 2 is via RE to ground.

Comment: @andy, compared to you, I'm a beginner in electronics! By your definition of "AC 0 volts" something like a capacitor connected to ground came to my mind. Unfortunately, I don't understand your answer yet. For example, why in your path 1, \$r_\text{e}\$ is connected to the base? According to the book, in emitter follower \$r_\text{e}\$ and \$R_\text{E}\$ are in parallel? So how can it be that one is connected to the base the other to ground?

Comment: @apadana you need to think in terms of AC ground and forget about the base being at a different DC voltage to ground. You also need to think that the base-emitter junction (basically a diode in series with re) is just a fixed volt-drop of around 0.6 volts in series with re. Then, lose all the DC offsets and just concentrate on the impedances hence, the 0.6 volts of the diode becomes a short to AC and the bias voltage of the base above ground is just a zero impedance of AC.

Comment: @andy, Thanks for your time and the helpful information.