# Are the AC resistances in the hybrid pi model and the T model of BJT the same?

Tags: transistors, bjt, small-signal, internal-resistance

[image: Hybrid Pi Model]
[image: T Model]

I have been wondering if the AC resistances in the two models of BJT circuit mean the same thing, that is
$$r_{c} = r_{c'}$$
$$r_{b} = r_{b'}$$
$$r_{ex} = r_{e'}$$

If they are different, please explain how.

[T model at Page 6](https://www.pearsonhighered.com/assets/samplechapter/0/1/3/4/0134420101.pdf)

[Hybrid Pi Model at Page 526](https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzacecu434bja7xldjzoyzj5x2padt4ea6emmvft5cfkrxrkg4vkcted6?filename=Donald%20A.%20Neamen%20-%20Microelectronics%20Circuit%20Analysis%20and%20Design%20%20-McGraw-Hill%20%282009%29.pdf)

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367321/confusion-about-the-meaning-of-re-and-r%cf%80/367430#367430

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No. They are not the same. Maybe except \$r_b\$.

\$r_b =r_b' = r_{bb}\$  - is a base spreading resistance (semiconductor resistance, bonding wires resistance).

And the same is true for \$r_{ex}\$ and \$r_c\$.
They are just emitter and collector ohmic resistance (bonding wires resistance etc. ) Not included in the T-model.

So, the dynamics resistance are:

$$r_{\pi} =\frac{V_T}{I_B} = (\beta +1)r_e'= (\beta +1) \frac{V_T}{I_E} \approx  (\beta +1) \frac{26\text{ mV}}{I_E}$$

$$r_e' = r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E} \approx \frac{26\text{ mV}}{I_E}$$

$$r_o = r_c' \approx \frac{V_A}{I_C}$$

\$V_T\$ - thermal voltage equal to about \$25\text{ mV}...26\text{ mV}\$ at room temperature.

\$V_A\$ - Early voltage (Early effect).

Comment: Can the contact resistances also be present in T model? Thank you.

Comment: For sure you can add it. But I do not see any benefices. We use T-model ("re" model) to do quick hand calculations.